# How to trigger a JS Event when any function/method is invoked/called in file

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a .js file in which I have many functions. So, my question is there any way to create CustomEvents in JavaScript which can be triggered as and when any function is called/invoked within that file?

Please guide me, also please suggest whether my thought process is in the right direction.

Comment: do you mean, without rewriting each function to dispatch an event when called?

Comment: Yes @JaromandaX, is it possible ?

Comment: quite simply, **no**

Comment: I can let you know right now that this solution is not the right one for you. If you post your problem, then we might be able to help you more. If you have access to the file on the server, then you could modify the functions themselves to trigger the events you are talking about.

Comment: can you post an example ? And also, how is that file used ?